# Locked chests in the dungeon: where to find the keys and what to expect inside?

Tags: terraria

The 1.2 update added some new locked chests to the dungeon. Where can I find their matching keys and what can I expect to find inside these chests? Are the rewards unique? Will I need to generate many worlds to get all significant rewards from these chests?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Hallowed Chest

  - Requires [Hallowed Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Key) to open
  - Always contains the [Rainbow Gun](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rainbow_Gun)
- Jungle Chest

  - Requires [Jungle Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Key) to open
  - Contains the [Piranha Gun](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Piranha_Gun)
- Frozen Chest

  - Requires [Frozen Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Frozen_key) to open
  - Always contains the [Staff of the Frost Hydra](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Staff_of_the_Frost_Hydra)
- Crimson Chest

  - Requires [Crimson Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Key) to open
  - Always contains the [Vampire Knives](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vampire_Knives)
- Corruption Chest

  - Requires [Corruption Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Corruption_Key) to open
  - Contains the [Scourge of the Corruptor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Scourge_of_the_corruptor)
- Golden Chest

  - Requires [Golden Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golden_Key) to open (See below how to acquire)
  - Contains either Magic Missile, Muramasa, Cobalt Shield, Aqua Scepter, Blue Moon, Handgun, Shadow Key or a new Golden Key

All of the rewards, except for those from Golden Chests, are unique to the dungeon.

All of the dungeon keys are acquired by combining a random drop from the respective hardmode biome with a [Temple Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Temple_Key) and 5 souls of Sight (Twins), Might (Destroyer) and Fright (Skeletron Prime).

In addition to these main rewards, all chests also contain some other items such as potions, explosives, materials, coins and lighting equipment.

Acquiring a Golden Key:

> Finding one in an unlocked, normal Chest in the Dungeon
>   Finding one in an unlocked, Living Wood Chest inside a Living Tree.
>   Killing a Dungeon Slime
>   Killing another Dungeon monster (1/67 chance)
>   Breaking a pot in the Dungeon (1/40 chance)

Sources:
My own dungeon delving
[Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Key)
**Source code of the game**

Comment: hallowed key is acquired from another dungeon chest? I don't think so... wiki disagrees, but then I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @Maslow I'm unsure where I found it, but I'm pretty sure it was a chest and not a drop.

Comment: @Zibbobz that was my edit 55 minutes ago

Comment: It's worth noting that this information is for 1.2.1. In v1.2 the keys simply dropped from biome mobs instead of the molds.

Comment: Wait, where did you get the source code? Is the game open source?

Comment: @Doorknob the disassembled code can be found online

Comment: "online" is pretty vague :P Where exactly? I am very curious about the design of the code now :D

Comment: @Doorknob You shouldn't have trouble finding it if you google terraria [version number] source code and check the first few results

Answer (score -1):

The key molds drop from mobs in that biome but in the ocean you can get any mold. I got the hallowed and Ice mold from beating lepus(the Easter boss) in those biomes after he spawned loads of disaster bunny's.after getting a mold you need 5 souls of fright,sight and might to craft a key.